# Play Framework 2.3.x how to run the sample applications?

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have Play 2.3.7 installed, and I have the `activator` command working with other play apps I have created locally.

However, when I try to clone the [Play Framework from github and run one of the 2.3.x sample applications](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.3.x/samples/java/forms) , the `activator` command fails with a Null Pointer Exception. Similarly, if I try to *import* the project into IntelliJ and build from the .sbt file, I get the same error:

[image: IntelliJ import error]

Is there something I need to change in the `build.sbt` file to get it to load properly? I'm guessing that it is something very simple that I am overlooking.

**TL;DR**: How do I run a Play 2.3.x sample application when cloned from [github](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.3.x/samples/java)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the exact play version that you have in [plugins.sbt](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/samples/java/forms/project/plugins.sbt)

From

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % System.getProperty("play.version"))
```

To(Assuming you are using play 2.3.1)

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.1")
```

Then `activator clean` then run again.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571939/when-i-run-the-play-framework-example-with-sbt-some-error)